# How to execute a python command over ssh

Tags: python, unix

I tried to execute the following command over ssh

```
ssh somehost $PY_PATH -c 'print "hello"'
```

The expected outcome should be "hello", but instead there was nothing. Why was this? What am I missing?

Comment: can it not be done in one command?

Comment: @Kasramvd This is the normal way to run a command remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shell thing. When you execute

```
ssh somehost $PY_PATH -c 'print "hello"'
```

that command line is parsed by the local shell before the part after `ssh somehost` is passed to the remote shell. I don't know where the `PY_PATH` variable comes from, but assuming its set properly on the remote system, you can escape the string on the local side so that it is correct on the remote side.

```
ssh somehost \$PY_PATH -c \'print \"hello\"\'
```

Comment: The dash isn't a meta character for the shell. The shell breaks the command into a list of parameters. The quotes tell it that it should ignore the inner spaces and treat the entire Python expression as a single parameter - and strips out the quotes so the program doesn't see them. Ssh reassembles the command string to pass to the other side but the quotes are missing so the remote she'll parsing splits it differently.

Answer (score 0):

login:

```
ssh -i pemfile user@host
```

go to python console with the command:

```
python
```

execute your command:

```
print "hello"
```

Comment: OP wants to execute a single python command via ssh, not open a long term terminal session or a long term python shell. OP would need to exit both of these before returning to the original local side shell.